# How to submit checkbox data-toggle value in form using PHP

Tags: php, html

I am submitting a form with checkbox input type which has data-toggle attribute and want to post the value when I submit the form.

I have submitted the form with onchange() function inside the input tag but can't post the value of the data-toggle in the submitted form

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="publish.php" method="post">
<label class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" onchange="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();" id="toggle_id" data-toggle="toggle" data-off="Disabled" data-on="Enabled">
   <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
</form>


publish.php
<?php
  $mode=$_POST['toggle'];
  if ($mode=='true')  
  {
    echo "good";
  }

  else if ($mode=='false')  
  {
    echo "bad";
   } 
?>
```

I want the form to post the value of the data-toggle to publish.php

Comment: You can't directly post the data attribute values in classic form submission. You will have to use the AJAX to submit the form.

Comment: Form submit doesn't send the "data-" information. You need to put these informations to another input like a hidden-input or you could send these via Javascript and Ajax

Answer (score 0):

*I am submitting a form with checkbox input type which has data-toggle attribute and want to post the value when I submit the form*

Then you will need to use jquery to ready the data-attribute value then use ajax to send that value to your php script.

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="publish.php" method="post">
<label class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="toggle_id" data-toggle="toggle" data-off="Disabled" data-on="Enabled">
   <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $('document').ready(function(){

      $('#toggle_id').on('change',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var toggleValue = $(this).data('toggle'); //value of data toggle

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            data : {toggleValue:toggleValue},
            dataType : 'json',
            encode : true,
            url    : "publish.php",
            success : function(response){

              // do something with the response
            }


        });
      })



  });
</script>
```

**publish.php**

```
<?php

    $toggle = isset($_POST['toggleValue']) ? $_POST['toggleValue'] : null;


  // $mode=$_POST['toggle'];
  // if ($mode=='true')  
  // {
  //   echo "good";
  // }

  // else if ($mode=='false')  
  // {
  //   echo "bad";
  //  } 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. The page doesn't load when I click the check box. I was expecting the form to submit and post the toggleValue to publish.php and perform some action with it.

Comment: @KwameAsante the page won't load as we use ajax the process happens in the background'

Comment: Thank you Sir, Is there a way I can get the page to load to publish.php?

Comment: Please read about Jquery ajax @KwameAsante then u will understand this concept